# Animate(slide-in/slide-out) the home indicator(mini-hamburger) icon

Tags: c#, android, actionbarsherlock, xamarin, indicator

Currently I've been given the opportunity to develop an android app. I've gotten very far already but there's one detail I can not figure out.

I'm trying to figure out how I can **"slide in"** and **"slide out"**, or whatever the correct term is, the home indicator icon (mini-hamburger). Do you guys know how to do this?

I've been trying to figure it out but I have been unable to find it.

See sample below:

[image: Home indicator icon enabled]

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to just the "mini-hamburger" indicator of the navigation drawer, or the whole app icon? If the former, what are you using for that indicator?

Comment: The "mini-hamburger" indeed. Currently I've set the indicator with the  actionbartoggle class:

_drawerToggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggle(this, _drawer,
    Resource.Drawable.ic_drawer_dark,
    Resource.String.DrawerOpen,
    Resource.String.DrawerClose);

Comment: Also I'm using Xamarin(C#) but Java examples are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

> The "mini-hamburger" indeed. Currently I've set the indicator with the actionbartoggle class: _drawerToggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggle(this, _drawer, Resource.Drawable.ic_drawer_dark, Resource.String.DrawerOpen, Resource.String.DrawerClose);

Assuming that is based off of [`ActionBarDrawerToggle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html), see if you have an equivalent of [the `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#setDrawerIndicatorEnabled%28boolean%29).

Comment: I do have this method but it appears to do absolutely nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Orion: I haven't used it, but based on the JavaDocs, I would have expected it to hide and show the mini-hamburger indicator.

Comment: I will ignore the setDrawerIndicatorEnabled() method because it just enables or disables the drawerindicator

I think I found something however. There appears to be a method that is in the example: OnDrawerSlide with the slideOffset property. I think I'll have to look into that.

Source: 
When the indicator is disabled, the ActionBar will revert to displaying the home-as-up indicator provided by the Activity's theme in the android.R.attr.homeAsUpIndicator attribute instead of the animated drawer glyph.

It just reverts to either the glyph or the image defined in the XML.

Comment: @Orion: According to your question, you want to '"enable/show" and "disable/hide"' the mini-hamburger. If that is not what you actually want, please edit your question.

Comment: My mistake, I always think people understand my train of thought with the explanation I give. Hence my 2 images. Showing the slide-in and slide-out state

Comment: @Orion: Oh. IMHO, if that's in the top 1000 things that you are worrying about with your app, it's too high.